# Sort ruby hash of array and hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

Is there any recursive way to sort a Hash which is composed by any other types of sortable data (typically hashes and arrays)?

I have

```
tagindex = Hash.new()
tagindex['keywords'] = Hash.new()
tagindex['authors'] = Hash.new()
tagindex['languages'] = Hash.new()
tagindex['licenses'] = Hash.new()
```

and for each `key` in `tagindex['keywords']`, `tagindex['keywords'][key]` is an Array.

Comment: Any data sample?

Comment: You can't sort a Hash, since it's not an ordered structure.

Comment: @Richard-Degenne not true just unnecessary. ruby `Hash`es have been ordered since 1.9.3 (based on key insertion order) and you can sort them using `Enumerable#sort` or `Enumerable#sort_by`

Comment: @engineersmnky, you'll admit that many things in Ruby are unnecessary, but potentially useful. I've posted several answers on SO that make good use of key-order in hashes. Frequently, as now, I try to find one, to link it, but am unsuccessful. I'll bookmark the next one.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yeah `"CarySwoveland" AND  "order" AND "hash" AND "ruby"  site:stackoverflow.com` returns *"About 364 results"*

Comment: @engineersmnky: Sure, but the `sort` and `sort_by` methods return Arrays, not Hashes.  I wasn't aware that Hashes were naturally ordered by key insertion order, but this sounds extremely brittle and I wouldn't recommend relying on that property in real-world applications.

Comment: How do `tagindex['keywords']` and `tagindex['authors']` affect the sorting? It might be easier to show some example data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

```
unordered_hash = {keywords: { a: 1, c: 2, b: 3}, authors: [ 1, 3, 4, 2]}
#=> {:keywords=>{:a=>1, :c=>2, :b=>3}, :authors=>[1, 3, 4, 2]}
unordered_hash.sort.to_h
#=> {:authors=>[1, 3, 4, 2], :keywords=>{:a=>1, :c=>2, :b=>3}}
```

Comment: While the OP has not made the question clear this answer is not technically incorrect, however it might make more sense to mix up the nested levels (like you did with the `Array`) to show that this does not sort at depth. Also this would benefit from a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could build your own logic with sort_by but it would get complicated quickly

I advise you to use the gem [deepsort](https://rubygems.org/gems/deepsort)

You haven't given much data but here is an example on what I suppose you have.

```
require "deepsort"
require 'json'

tagindex = {
  keywords: { keyword3: "contents3", keyword2: "contents2", keyword1: "contents1"}, 
  authors: [ "author2",  "author1",  "author4",  "author3"]
}

puts JSON.pretty_generate(tagindex.deep_sort)

=>
{
  "authors": [
    "author1",
    "author2",
    "author3",
    "author4"
  ],
  "keywords": {
    "keyword1": "contents1",
    "keyword2": "contents2",
    "keyword3": "contents3"
  }
}
```